# What kind of backdoor can be made after hacking wi-fi?

Tags: passwords, wifi, backdoor

I'm interested to know if A hacks B's wifi password, what can A do to gain persistent access to the router even after B changes the wifi password? Secondly, how can we detect the backdoor and patch it?

Comment: Once the wifi password has changed you lose access to the network - any backdoor would have to connect outwards from the network. You could think of the problem in the same way as "how do you plant a backdoor if you only get one shot to physically be connected to the network?" There are numerous ways to do this depending on your focus. Can you narrow your question down a little?

Comment: Being wifi, you could re-hack the wifi password, but that's not what you're asking

Comment: @schroeder you right, wifi password is can be re-hacked. let imagine that we have access to router's configuration page. I know that we can inject some codes to firmware but it's absolutely technical.

Comment: Most routers have some kind of setting that allows access to the admin login page from the WAN interface (Internet). Turn this on, and you have access to the router. As for installing exploits, that would really depend on the router.

Comment: @schroeder what if target's use dynamic IP? it would be too difficult.

Comment: difficult or not, the problem remains that the only way to do what you want is to either reconfigure the router or exploit an install malware

Comment: You could try looking at the router's firmware for vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attacker with admin access to your wifi router can install a firmware "update" that contains any number of nasty things, such as a back-door for shell access or a secret password that will always allow access.

Real life example: The [DNSChanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSChanger) trojan configured a rogue DNS server that would direct all of your advertising traffic to the DNSChanger team's own advertising network.  This was quite invisible; who cares if you're getting ads from a different ad network?  Doubleclick, for one.  DNSChanger has a really great [takedown story](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2011/11/how-the-most-massive-botnet-scam-ever-made-millions-for-estonian-hackers/) and [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9n2dQ7Fv6A) if you're interested.

(DNSChanger was primarily a Windows trojan, but it also compromised wifi routers, which are a *lot* harder to repair.)

To safeguard your router, make sure its firmware is up to date and that your admin password is a strong one that is very different from both your access password and the router's default password.

*Detecting* a compromise is basically impossible.  If you are concerned, wipe the router:

1. Remove the antennae and LAN cables except your own laptop (to prevent access for now)
2. Copy the configuration down on a piece of paper (a compromise could come with a backup!)
3. If it's possible, try a factory reset (you can't trust it, but it could help)
4. Flash the router with the latest firmware (even if it's the same version you have installed)
5. Copy the config back to the device
6. Change all passwords
7. Reattach the antennae and LAN cables